# Rails 4 query on delegated attribute from has_many association

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 4 app (with PostgreSQL DB) I have the following model structure:

```
class Product
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end

class User
  has_one :profile
  delegate :name, to: :profile
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm having trouble doing a query for `Items` on a `Product` by the item's user name. A few things I've tried:

```
Product.first
    .items
    .includes(:user)
    .where("user.name = ?", "Blah")
    .references(:user)

Item.where(product_id: 2)
    .includes(:user)
    .where("user.name = ?", "Blah")
    .references(:user)
```

I've also tried things like the below with no success:

```
Product.first
    .items
    .includes(user: :profile)
    .where("items.user.profile.name = ?", "Blah")
    .references(:user)
```

All of the above queries give me syntax errors. I'm sure I'm doing something silly but am wondering if anyone can help me figure out how to perform my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Product.first.items.joins(user: :profile).where(profiles: {name: "Blah"})
```

Comment: Agh, I tried something similar and was using `profile` not `profiles`. Thanks!